# How to solve [ plugin:elasticsearch Authentication Exception ] in elasticsearch using shield

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, installshield, kibana

[plugin:elasticsearch - Authentication Exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NfVhs.png)

How to solve exception that is marked in above image link?

Answer (score 3):

In your Kibana installation in /config/kibana.yml  you have to set the username and password that Kibana should use to access Elasticsearch.

Comment: In kibana.yml file , all coding line are blocked with #. How can i set username and password?

Comment: Just delete the `#` characters on those lines.